# Reduce karma required for commenting

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

New users start with 1 karma point, which means that they can't post comments right away. This leads to "comment answers", because new users have no other choice. We have this issue already over at ROS Answers (see [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/54550/reduce-karma-required-for-commenting/)) and it is starting [here](http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1474/weird-texture-mapping-in-collada-meshes-130/) as well.

I also found out that on AskBot's Q&A this limit is set to 1 (see [here](http://askbot.org/en/faq/)).

Hence, I suggest we lower it to 1 as well.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1487/reduce-karma-required-for-commenting/) by [bit-pirate](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/143/bit-pirate/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 129 on 2013-02-21

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2013-03-07**:
Thanks. Change has been made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Just posting this answer to close the question.
@nkoenig has reduced the karma to one as suggested. Thanks!

---

Originally posted by [bit-pirate](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/143/bit-pirate/) with karma: 129 on 2013-03-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1